# How to setup up Zeppelin to use SQL Server Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, windows-authentication, apache-zeppelin, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to get my Zeppelin notebook to use Windows Authentication to connect to MS SQL Server. I've gotten local authentication to work using the JDBC. I've gotten Zeppelin working authentication with Active Directory. This is the final step to get the notebook to working. This should be possible right?

In my interpreter I have:

**Properties**

```
zeppelin.jdbc.auth.type = Kerberos
zeppelin.jdbc.integratedSecurity = true
```

**Dependencies**

```
/opt/zeppelin/interpreter/mssql/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
```

But when I try out my notebook I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$AuthenticationMethod
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.security.JDBCSecurityImpl.getAuthtype(JDBCSecurityImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.security.JDBCSecurityImpl.createSecureConfiguration(JDBCSecurityImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.open(JDBCInterpreter.java:190)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

zeppelin.jdbc.auth.type = true is not a valid setting

> Types of authentications' methods supported are SIMPLE, and KERBEROS

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/jdbc.html#more-properties

Comment: My mistake, I wrote the post wrong, I am using auth type = Kerberos but I still get the above error.